# Admin on rest - element does not exist warning

Tags: mongoose, graphql, admin-on-rest

I'm using admin on rest with the graphql client.
When i create a element and hit the save button the page is redirect to the list view and the message "Element created" appear followed by "Element does not exist".

The element is created correctly in the database.
Any idea on the second message warning?

Comment: An issue has been raised on the aor-graphql repository about this. I'll investigate ASAP and let you know

Comment: Is it related to https://github.com/marmelab/aor-graphql/issues/34 ?

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue on the demo app. Can you setup a minimal repository reproducing it ?

Comment: i'm basically using the same code of this demo app [link](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest-graphql-demo)

Comment: Sorry but on the demo, you can create a product without issue, so you probably have changed something. Can you share some code ?